# count value is display on android emulator via soap webservice

Tags: java, android, mysql, soap

I have tried display a value in Android, that was retrieved via a soap call. But I can't make it work. If I run my application, the count value is displayed on my tomcat-apache. But the count value is not displayed on my android emulator. why is the count value not displayed here.
Please help me. I know the reason. But I can't figure out the code part. My mistake is my android code part. where I can change my code.

This is my webservice code:

```
public class RetailerWs {

public String customerData(){
String customerInfo = "";
try{
Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/xcart-432pro","root","");
//Find customer information where the customer ID is maximum
PreparedStatement statement =  con.prepareStatement("select * from xcart_orders where status='Q' AND date = CURDATE()");

 ResultSet result = statement.executeQuery();

  int count=0;    
   while(result.next()){

 count++;
 System.out.println(count);
 }
  }

 catch(Exception exc){
    System.out.println(exc.getMessage());
  }

   return customerInfo;
    }

   }
```

This is my android code part:

```
   public class RetailerActivity extends Activity {
   private static final String SOAP_ACTION = "http://xcart.com/customerData";
   private static final String METHOD_NAME = "customerData";
   private static final String NAMESPACE = "http://xcart.com";
   private static final String URL = "http://192.168.1.168:8085/XcartLogin/services/RetailerWs?wsdl";
     /** Called when the activity is first created. */
    @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.retrieve);
    SoapObject request = new SoapObject(NAMESPACE, METHOD_NAME); 

    SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(SoapEnvelope.VER11);

    envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);

    HttpTransportSE ht = new HttpTransportSE(URL);
    try {
        ht.call(SOAP_ACTION, envelope);
        SoapPrimitive response = (SoapPrimitive)envelope.getResponse();
        SoapPrimitive s = response;
        String str = s.toString();
        String resultArr[] = str.split("&");//Result string will split & store in an array

        TextView tv = new TextView(this);

        for(int i = 0; i<resultArr.length;i++){
        tv.append(resultArr[i]+"\n\n");
       }
        setContentView(tv);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
       }
      }
      }
```

Where I should change my android code to print the count value on the android emulator.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that you are getting some value in TextView ?  You can set TextView in android in the following manner.

```
 LinearLayout lLayout = (LinearLayout)findViewById(R.id.l_layout); // This is my main layout

 TextView tv = new TextView(this);
 tv.setText("Akshay");  // Here I set the value to TextView
 lLayout.addView(tv);   // Here I am adding this view in main View.
```

Hope this helps :)